# How to add border around the pdf page when converting it from html

Tags: html, css, pdf-generation, puppeteer, html-to-pdf

I want to add a border around the pdf when converting it from html. I tried using @page css but it does seem to work. What might be the best to achieve this ? I do not want to use position fixed to the body or any other div because if it goes beyond the page, it will be an issue there.

**NOTE: Running the snippet will open the print window.**

```js
window.print();
```

```css
 *,
        ::after,
        ::before {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        html {
            font-family:'sans-serif';
            line-height: 1.15;
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;
            -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: 400;
            line-height: 1.5;
            color: #000000;
            text-align: left;
            background-color: #fff;
        }

        .wrapper {
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 20px;
        }

        @page {
            size: A4;
            margin-top: 0.25in;
            margin-bottom: 0.25in;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Html</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus in ornare quam viverra. Rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque. Purus sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor. Massa tincidunt dui ut ornare lectus sit. At auctor urna nunc id cursus metus aliquam. Diam quam nulla porttitor massa id neque aliquam vestibulum morbi. Quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus suspendisse. Nam at lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus. Sem nulla pharetra diam sit. Viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel facilisis volutpat. Ut enim blandit volutpat maecenas. Vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant morbi. Pharetra massa massa ultricies mi quis hendrerit dolor. Tincidunt augue interdum velit euismod in pellentesque massa placerat duis.

</p>
      <p>Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis. Et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas sed tempus. Ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit pellentesque. Varius vel pharetra vel turpis. Velit sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas purus. Aliquam sem et tortor consequat id porta. Orci porta non pulvinar neque laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur libero. Elit duis tristique sollicitudin nibh sit amet commodo. Vel turpis nunc eget lorem dolor sed viverra. Aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt. Viverra nam libero justo laoreet sit amet. Phasellus vestibulum lorem sed risus ultricies tristique nulla aliquet enim. Accumsan tortor posuere ac ut consequat semper. Vulputate enim nulla aliquet porttitor lacus luctus. Eget duis at tellus at urna condimentum mattis pellentesque. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit ut.

</p>
      <p>Tincidunt praesent semper feugiat nibh. Cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed blandit libero. Aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac ut. Consectetur adipiscing elit duis tristique sollicitudin. Amet dictum sit amet justo donec. Convallis posuere morbi leo urna molestie. Eu facilisis sed odio morbi. Mi eget mauris pharetra et ultrices neque ornare aenean euismod. Feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc faucibus a pellentesque sit. Semper quis lectus nulla at volutpat diam. Sit amet nisl suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis. Iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit. In iaculis nunc sed augue lacus. Sed felis eget velit aliquet sagittis id. Morbi tristique senectus et netus et. Fames ac turpis egestas sed tempus urna et pharetra pharetra. In ornare quam viverra orci sagittis eu volutpat odio facilisis. Viverra accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque eu ultrices vitae. Nunc eget lorem dolor sed viverra. Sollicitudin nibh sit amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula.

</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@media print`

```js
window.print();
```

```css
@media print {
    body{
        border:12px solid red;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Html</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus in ornare quam viverra. Rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque. Purus sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor. Massa tincidunt dui ut ornare lectus sit. At auctor urna nunc id cursus metus aliquam. Diam quam nulla porttitor massa id neque aliquam vestibulum morbi. Quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus suspendisse. Nam at lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus. Sem nulla pharetra diam sit. Viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel facilisis volutpat. Ut enim blandit volutpat maecenas. Vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant morbi. Pharetra massa massa ultricies mi quis hendrerit dolor. Tincidunt augue interdum velit euismod in pellentesque massa placerat duis.

</p>
      <p>Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis. Et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas sed tempus. Ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit pellentesque. Varius vel pharetra vel turpis. Velit sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas purus. Aliquam sem et tortor consequat id porta. Orci porta non pulvinar neque laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur libero. Elit duis tristique sollicitudin nibh sit amet commodo. Vel turpis nunc eget lorem dolor sed viverra. Aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt. Viverra nam libero justo laoreet sit amet. Phasellus vestibulum lorem sed risus ultricies tristique nulla aliquet enim. Accumsan tortor posuere ac ut consequat semper. Vulputate enim nulla aliquet porttitor lacus luctus. Eget duis at tellus at urna condimentum mattis pellentesque. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit ut.

</p>
      <p>Tincidunt praesent semper feugiat nibh. Cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed blandit libero. Aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac ut. Consectetur adipiscing elit duis tristique sollicitudin. Amet dictum sit amet justo donec. Convallis posuere morbi leo urna molestie. Eu facilisis sed odio morbi. Mi eget mauris pharetra et ultrices neque ornare aenean euismod. Feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc faucibus a pellentesque sit. Semper quis lectus nulla at volutpat diam. Sit amet nisl suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis. Iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit. In iaculis nunc sed augue lacus. Sed felis eget velit aliquet sagittis id. Morbi tristique senectus et netus et. Fames ac turpis egestas sed tempus urna et pharetra pharetra. In ornare quam viverra orci sagittis eu volutpat odio facilisis. Viverra accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque eu ultrices vitae. Nunc eget lorem dolor sed viverra. Sollicitudin nibh sit amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula.

</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: hmm but this only has the border around the text. I wanted the border to be covering the whole page.